# Custom UiTableViewCell element errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

A quick run down of my problem.

I have a tableView which loads a custom UITableViewCell from the bundle and displays it. This all works perfectly and gives me the desired effect that i want.

During the loading of the "Custom Cell" I'm trying to perform some changes to elements within the custom cell, specifically a UILabel. Below is the code from my CustomCell.m

```
//  ListCustomCell.m
//  Recycling Lives SOS
//
//  Created by Scott Evans on 08/04/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Recycling-Lives. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ListCustomCell.h"

@implementation ListCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;
    NSLog(@"Debug Tracking. This outputs into the debug, so is definately being called");
    self.material.text = @"TEST";

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

The Label that i am trying to edit. Simply does not get edited. Ive tried using a number of different element like UIButtons to see if they have the same problem, Unfortunately they do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: How are you changing the text. Can you show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: check if self.material is not nil

Comment: Im trying to set the text from this class. Its not just text that i can't change. I can't change CGRects, images or anything is seems.

Comment: Move `self.material.text = @"TEST";` to `- (void)awakeFromNib` method. Don't forget to call `[super awakeFromNib];`

Comment: Ok so it turns out my self.material is (null). Why would this be?

Comment: I moved the `self.material.text = @"TEST";`. This now works.

Comment: I have a different custom cell setup which implements this method

Comment: `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake (200, 10, 180, 50);
    [self.priceSegments setFrame:frame];
    return self;
}`

Comment: How come this method works and updates properly but this new one doesn't.

Comment: `awakeFromNib` ensures that all connections to other objects in the nib have been established. You can find more details from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib)